# Node JS comma assignment

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was reading a [blog post](https://shinesolutions.com/2011/08/26/asynchronous-code-design-with-node-js/) and came across the following code snippet:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    filenames,
    i,
    processId;

filenames = fs.readdirSync(".");
for (i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
    console.log(filenames[i]);
}
console.log("Ready.");

processId = process.getuid();
```

I'm curious about:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    filenames,
    i,
    processId;
```

Is this an example of the comma operator:

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the second operand.

If so I still don't really grok what's going on. Is the following statement the same as writing something like:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var filenames;
var i;
var processId;
```

Would the following be valid:

```
var foo = require('./foo.js'),
    bar = require('./bar.js'),
    baz = require('./baz.js'),
    input = "some string",
    i,j,k;
```

And evaluate to:

```
var foo = require('./foo.js'),
var bar = require('./bar.js');
var baz = require('./baz.js');
var input = "some string";
var i;
var j;
var k;
```

Comment: Please don't change your question significally!

Comment: Especially when some answers are posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the comma operator. The comma is part of the syntax for the `var` keyword. The `var` keyword is specified to take a list of variables separated by commas.

This feature is called a `VariableDeclarationList` in the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement

The `var` keyword syntax is specified as:

```
Syntax

VariableStatement[Yield]:
    var VariableDeclarationList[In, ?Yield];

VariableDeclarationList[In, Yield]:
    VariableDeclaration[?In, ?Yield]
    VariableDeclarationList[?In, ?Yield], VariableDeclaration[?In, ?Yield]

VariableDeclaration[In, Yield]:
    BindingIdentifier[?Yield] Initializer[?In, ?Yield]opt
    BindingPattern[?Yield] Initializer[?In, ?Yield]
```

If you're not familiar with BNF or RBNF notation. The specification above means:

1. VariableStatement is defined as:

   1. the string `var` followed by a VariableDeclarationList
2. VariableDeclarationList is defined as either:

   1. VariableDeclaration or
   2. VariableDeclarationList, VariableDeclaration

      - Note: this is a recursive definition. Basically it defines an
        an infinite list of VariableDeclaration, VariableDeclaration, VariableDeclaration ...
3. VariableDeclaration is defined as

   1. BindingIdentifier followed by an optional Initializer or
   2. BindingPattern followed by an Initializer

      - Note: this BindingPattern definition is for the new ES6 destructuring assignment ([a,b,c] = ...)

The definitions for `BindingIdentifier`, `BindingPattern` and `Initializer` are specified elsewhere in the spec.

The definition of `BindingIdentifier` is basically a variable name. So valid `BindingIdentifiers` are things like `hello` or `x` or `y2` but not `for` (because it's a keyword) or `1k` (because it starts with a number).

I'll ignore the definition of `BindingPattern` for now because it's not strictly necessary to understand the variable list definition.

The definition of `Initializer` is the symbol `=` followed by an expression. Basically `=` followed by any javascript code.

So, a `VariableDeclaration` (NOT the `var` keyword, just one part of it) is defined simply as:

```
anyVariableName = anything
```

or

```
anyVariableName // remember, Initializer is optional
```

And the `var` keyword is defined as either:

```
var VariableDeclaration
```

or

```
var VariableDeclaration, VariableDeclaration, VariableDeclaration ...
```

So. Valid examples of the `var` keyword syntax include

```
var x;

var x = 12;

var x,
    y = "hello",
    z;

var x = 0,
    y,
    z=100;
```

etc.

When we include the `BindingPattern` definition then valid examples of the `var` keyword syntax also include:

```
var x=10,
    [a,b,c] = [100,200,300],
    i,
    j;

var {x,y,z} = {x:10,y:20,z:30},
    a = 2,
    b,
    c,
    [i,j,k]=["hello","cruel","world"];
```

---

Additional notes:

Note that `VariableDeclaration` can also happen without the `var` keyword. For example:

```
a = 40; // if this is the first time a is defined then it is 
        // automatically created as a global variable
```

In this case, since there is no `var` keyword, any comma that appears would not be part of the `var` syntax. Which means that without the `var` keyword the comma is a comma operator:

```
a = 10, b = 50; // comma operator
```

Comment: One of the things I don't like about languages that inherit C-style syntax is that symbols can have different meanings depending on what syntax it is a part of.

Comment: was my interpretation correct? Could you provide a small example?

Comment: @mbigras: I didn't think an example is necessary since you provided one yourself in your question.

Comment: would it be possible to do multiple assignment using this sytnax? For example in ruby I can write `a, b, c = 42, "foo", "bar"`. Just wondering if this is the same type of thing that's going on.

Comment: @mbigras No. The list is merely multiple declarations separated by commas. So do multiple assignments you must do `a=42,b="foo",c="bar"`. You can do multiple assignments by array destructuring but that is a different syntax

Comment: @mbigras FYI. This syntax comes from C and also exist in C++, Go etc.

Comment: so is the main point to declare all variables and assign one (in this case `fs`)?

Comment: @mbigras Yes. Like most other C-like languages

Comment: @mbigras: Yes, all your examples in your question are valid. Perhaps I'll quote the relevant sections of the spec directly.

Comment: that would be great! Would be happy to accept your answer if you add some quotes and maybe an example. As it stands cmd+f ing your link doesn't help that much

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a comma operator.

```
var a="1,2,3", b=[1,2,3]; // No comma operators in this line

if (a == b)
  alert("Yes"), a = null; // Comma operator

if (a += 10, b) // Comma operator
  b[1,2] = a;   // Comma operator

a = (1,2,b[3]); // Comma operator
```

Comma in `var` statement separates different variables, so yes, it is equivalent of multiple vars.